# Displaying millions of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, 2d, heatmap

I have somewhere between 2M and 10M static objects which I would like overlay on Google Maps. I've previously tried [HeatmapLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer) successfully on much smaller sets. Due to the shear volume I'm a bit concerned, and I must to lump the objects together to avoid performance problems. The target platform is Chrome on a standard desktop.

What is the best way to space partition and merge objects in close proximity? Should I try some type of loose quad tree to lump the objects together, and then display each node with its respective weight using the `HeatmapLayer`? Or should I try to dynamically build some type of triangle mesh where vertices can be dynamically merged and triangles gain weight as more objects are added to them and then display the triangles on top of Google Maps? HeatmapLayer is pretty fast (looks like it's implemented in GL shaders), but I doubt [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) is.

I've tried searching for open source **loose** quad tree JavaScript implementations and other fast space partition JavaScript implementations but found nothing. Is my best bet to port some C++ implementation? Any answers/comments from someone who built something similar would be helpful!

Comment: It seems that you would want to pre-group your static objects into systematic zones.  Then, when you have a given piece of map to display, you can calculate which zones intersect with your viewport and then deal only with the subset of objects in the overlapping zones.  I could imagine that often times, you'd only have one zone that overlaps with the viewport.  This can even be multi-level such that a zone contains sub-zones and you repeat the process to narrow it down further to just the relevant sub-zones.

Comment: Have you seen the article ["Too Many Markers"](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation?  For lots of markers you will probably  want to use a tile based rendering solution (FusionTablesLayer, KmlLayer, or a custom map type with tiles you render on your server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on preprocessing my data in the backend using a [space partitioning implementation](https://github.com/highfestiva/kazaamtree). I recommend it for anybody who has the luxury of doing so.